# Angularjs nested custom directives

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create some kind of store where html looks like this:

```
<body>
   <main-wrapper>

    <head>
    </head>

    <wrapper-one>
       <products>
       </products>
    </wrapper-one>

    <wrapper-two>
        <log-in>
        </log-in>
    </wrapper-two>

    </main-wrapper>
</body>
```

Point of this practise is that i don't use controllers at all. Just directives. I want to make these directives communicate with each other. So let's say when i log in i want to change each products from 'green' to 'blue'.

Here is the directives:

```
app.directive("mainWrapper", function () {

return {
            transclude:true,
            restrict:'E',
            template: '<div class="container" ng-transclude></div>',
            controller : function($scope){
                this.addItem = function(val){
                    console.log(val);
                }
            }
        };
});

app.directive("wrapperOne", function () {

return {
            restrict:'E',
            transclude:true,
            require : '^mainWrapper',
            template: '<div class="col-sm-8" ng-transclude></div>',
            controller : function($scope){
                this.addItem = function(val){
                    console.log(val);
                }
            }
        };
});

app.directive("wrapperTwo", function () {

return {
            restrict:'E',
            require : '^wrapperOne',
            templateUrl: 'view/products.html',
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.products = 
                    [{product : 'car',color : 'green'}];
            }
        };
});

app.directive("logIn", function () {

return {
            restrict:'E',
            require : ['^wrapperTwo', '?products'],
            scope: true,
            link:function($scope,elem,attr,outerctrl){

            },
            templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
             //login -> $scope.loggedIn = true
             //logout -> $scope.loggedIn = false
            }
        };
});
```

I tried to make this question short so i left some code out of this. So when user logs in and scope loggedIn is true, i want to change the color of product. I've been struggling with this a while now and little help would be awesome.

I rewrited this code to here because i made it shorter and to english. I am sure there is some typos in code but dont worry about them. All templates are working and the page looks right with original code.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Inside of main wrapper i did this:

```
this.allProds = function (x) {
    this.products = [{ product: "car", color: x}];

    return this.products;
}
```

And now i can use this where ever i want. Example from products directive:

```
var products = outercontrol.allProds('blue');
```